# What do we use the diameter of a circle for?

Tags: math-history, constants

Today, the 14<sup>th</sup> of March, is $\pi$ day (in America the date is 3-14 - in the rest of the world today's date is 14-3).

We define [$\pi=\frac{C}{d}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumference). Yet, that seems to be the last time we use the diameter $d$, immediately switching to the radius $r$, e.g. $C=2\pi r$, $A=\pi r^2$, etc. I know I've seen lots of formulae using $r$, but I'm not aware of seeing any other formulae using $d$.

What formulae (other than the identity for $\pi$) use the diameter $d$ in preference to the radius $r$ as the canonical version of the formula?

Obviously, we can change any formula that uses $r$ to use $\frac{d}{2}$ instead, but that's not the point. Where do we already use $d$ in preference to $r$?

P.S. I am aware of $\tau=\frac{C}{r}$: using it we get $C=\tau r$ instead.

Comment: I think that the question has no "historical" relevance... The *diameter* is there: it divides the circle in two: fullstop. Is this fact relevant ?  Maybe...

Comment: From an historical perspective, we have to note that in anicnt math there were geometrical entities and definitions but not algebraic formulas: thus we have a *ratio* between two magnitudes: the lenght of the circumference and the lenght of the diameter and not a "number" (in the modern sense).

Answer (score 1):

For every formulae with $ d $,  we can change it to expression of $ r $, and expression in $ r $ gives us more possibilities  to integers, than expression in $ d $. If you want to express it in $d$    , just change $r$    to $d/2$    .

Comment: Please familiarise yourself with the meaning of [_canonical_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/canonical).

Answer (score 1):

Well, in modern mathematics the diameter is well established as an important notion in general metric spaces; and the main issue here is that in general, the diameter $d$ is *not* twice the radius $r$ (rather, $r\le d\le 2r$). So yes, plenty of formulae are out there (in metric spaces) involving the diameter instead of the radius: for instance, it is a basic fact of graph theory that in each graph there is a cycle whose length is at most $2d+1$.

Comment: Does that diameter relate to circles?

Comment: No. The notion of diameter for general metric spaces is explained here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Bounded_and_totally_bounded_spaces

Comment: OK. My question is pretty circle-themed and I didn't know before that there are non-circular uses for diameters. So thanks for expanding my knowledge, but you didn't answer the question as I intended it to be understood.

Comment: Well, I think the problem with your question is that people realized pretty early in human history that the diameter is twice the radius.